# displayDialog method return value causes error -1700 when used as string argument

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation

When I try printing the `Var 'password'` it says

> Error -1700: Can't convert types.

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;


var text = Application('System Events')
//prompt
var password = app.displayDialog('enter your password', {defaultAnswer: " "});
text.keystroke(password)
//returned message is Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

Comment: Are you trying to log the password variable? Perhaps instead of text.keystroke() you want to use `console.log(password)`. To view the things that you have logged, choose "Show Log" from the "View" menu, and then select the "Messages" tab in the bottom half of the window, and re-run the script. Alternatively, the last statement of your script is its return value, so if you just make the last line of your script `password;` (no "var"!) then you should see its value printed in the bottom of the ScriptEditor window when the script finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `displayDialog` command returns an `AlertReply` record, which looks like this in JXA:

```
{"buttonReturned":"OK", "textReturned":"password"}
```

To get the value entered in the dialog, try appending `.textReturned` to the `displayDialog` invocation, like this:

```
var password = app.displayDialog('enter your password', {defaultAnswer: " "}).textReturned;
```